# Resetting pst password on a system that is using Symantic Endpoint Protection

Tags: password, outlook

I work for a company that employs Symantec Endpoint Protection. I have a user that has forgotten the password to their pst file. I've tried running a few password reset programs but Symantec treats them as viruses and will not allow me to complete the task. Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but you were down voted because this is easily searchable.  I went ahead and answered regardless.  Hope it helps... let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Just for the record: We don't mind easilly googleable questions, because we would like *this* site to be the first result when people google for things. So downvotes for "easy" or "googleable" questions are uncool.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need admin rights depending on how Symantec is managed, but if you disable Symantec it should allow you to run whatever you want to run.  Click [HERE](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic114351.html) for a great post on how to disable most common AV/Security applications.

I shouldn't have to note this, but I will anyway:  Disabling Symantec is typically not a good idea.  It's better to disconnect from your internal network before doing this as its possible for malware to remain inactive until such an opportunity presents itself.